# Building GCC cross compiler (from "Linux" to "Windows")

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cross-platform

I want to build "gcc cross-compiler" to compile "c/c++" applications on "Linux" environment but for "Windows" target.

I have made this so far:

1. Installed the necessary tools and packages for building GCC listed on "[Prerequisites for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html)" page.
2. Downloaded required sources:
   "[gcc-core-4.4.1](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.4.1/gcc-core-4.4.1.tar.bz2)", "[gcc-g++-4.4.1](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.4.1/gcc-g++-4.4.1.tar.bz2)", "[binutils-2.19.1](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.19.1.tar.bz2)", "[w32api-3.13-mingw32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW%20API%20for%20MS-Windows/Current%20Release_%20w32api-3.13/w32api-3.13-mingw32-src.tar.gz/download)", "[mingwrt-3.16-mingw32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW%20Runtime/mingwrt-3.16/mingwrt-3.16-mingw32-src.tar.gz/download)"
3. Created this directory hierarchy:
   "${HOME}/gcc/" - for final cross-compiler
   "${HOME}/src/" - for sources
   "${HOME}/src/build-binutils/i386-mingw32/" - for building binutils to "i386-mingw32" target
   "${HOME}/src/build-gcc/i386-mingw32/" - for building gcc to "i386-mingw32" target
4. Builded binutils package:

   cd "${HOME}/src/build-binutils/i386-mingw32/"
   ../../binutils-2.19.1/configure --prefix="${HOME}/gcc" --target=i386-mingw32 --disable-nls
   make
   make install
5. Copied "w32api" and "mingwrt" headers to the install directory:

   cp -R "${HOME}/src/w32api-3.13-mingw32/include" "${HOME}/gcc/i386-mingw32"
   cp -R "${HOME}/src/mingwrt-3.16-mingw32/include" "${HOME}/gcc/i386-mingw32"

And now when I am trying to build the "c (only) cross-compiler":

```
cd "${HOME}/src/build-gcc/i386-mingw32/"
../../gcc-4.4.1/configure --prefix="${HOME}/gcc" --target=i386-mingw32 --enable-languages=c --with-headers="${HOME}/gcc/i386-mingw32/include" --disable-nls
make<br>
```

it was building something about 4 minutes and then gives me these errors:

```
${HOME}/gcc/i386-mingw32/bin/ld: dllcrt2.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libgcc_s.dll] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `${HOME}/src/build-gcc/i386-mingw32/i386-mingw32/libgcc'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `${HOME}/src/build-gcc/i386-mingw32'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From that error message I really don't know what to do now :-((( .

Does anybody know where is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's actually OK: the way things go, you need to

1. build binutils
2. install headers
3. build the a partial C compiler: enough to create object files, but not enough to link
4. build the win32api and mingw runtime (which includes your missing `dllcrt2.o`)
5. build a complete C compiler (and other front-ends, such as C++, Fortran, Ada, whatever, if you want them)

You have successful performed step 3 above; it fails building libgcc (which is a GCC support library), but that means the C compiler core is functionnal (although it won't be able to link, it can still create valid object files). You can check that by looking at the `gcc/xgcc` file in your GCC build directory.

So, you need to go to the next step, not worrying about your current failure.

(To actuall install the partial C compiler, you should run `make` with the `-k` option, to have it do it best, even in the face of errors. For example, use `make -k install`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment: "You have successfuly performed step 3 above". I thought if I get any error I cannot go to the next step, but (fortunately) I was wrong. Next I successfully compiled win32api, but I got some errors when I tried to compile mingwrt - something was wrong with "threading". So I decided to compile gcc with these parameters: --prefix="${HOME}/gcc" --target=i386-mingw32 --program-prefix=i386-mingw32 --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-headers="${HOME}/gcc/i386-mingw32/include" --disable-nls --disable-threads --disable-shared --disable-libssp.

And this worked!!!

Comment: I am sorry for a little mistake from previous comment: the problem was in "shared" option and NOT with "threads" option. So it compiled also without "--disable-threads" specified.

Comment: Regarding threads, you can also build GCC with `--enable-libgomp`  (for OpenMP) if you have the pthreads-win32 library installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are precompiled cross-compilers of MinGW-w64 available.
This allows to compile native 32- and 64-bit Windows binaries from Linux, a two minute tutorial is available at http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

Just in case you don't want to spend a lot of time trying to build it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I grepped through the MinGW sources, and found that dllcrt2.o is something built off the mingwrt package. I assume you have to compile and install that, not just copy the headers?

Comment: Yes, yes.
Copying headers is just one from many steps.
After the 5th step in my post I should do this:

-6. Build "c (only) cross-compiler".
-7. Add the location with just compiled binaries to "PATH" environment variable.
-8. Build "win32api".
-9. Build "mingwrt".
-10. Build "c and c++ cross-compiler".

But for now I am just at 6th step and getting that error.

Comment: Hmmm... haven't toyed with MinGW myself. But when I set up a first-stage cross-compiler, I use "--without-headers" on the configure line to tell it not to rely on any kind of C library or runtime for the target. I don't know which how-to you are following or how things work with MinGW, but perhaps you give it a shot.