# Compile Qt application for Windows Mobile 5

Tags: c++, qt, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm trying to compile a small Qt application for windows Mobile 5.
so I've few questions:

- currently i'm using ubuntu 9.10, I've hear some thing about cross-compilation but I din't found a real example of have to do it. Will it be possible to compile from linux?
- How to compile an application for mobile anywhere(windows(VS, mingw,etc), linux(cmake,qmake, etc))

tnx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compile applications for Windows Mobile 5 you will need either:

- at least Visual Studio 2005 Standard or Visual Studio 2008 Professional (Microsoft has moved Windows Mobile support in the Professional Version). 
  **Note:** You cannot use the Express versions of Visual Studio to create applications for Windows Mobile platform.
- [CeGCC](http://cegcc.sourceforge.net/) which can be crosscompiled from Linux.

Regarding Qt on Windows Mobile, you should read this Dr. Dobb's Article: [Qt and Windows CE](http://www.ddj.com/mobile/208200263)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definative answer but I am not sure a cross compiler exists that does what you want to do.

Check this questions and answer regarding cross compiler for windows/linux: [Building GCC cross compiler (from “Linux” to “Windows”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474673/building-gcc-cross-compiler-from-linux-to-windows)

I know you mention Qt but you also may want to check out the following posts regarding building for Windows Mobile from Linux using the Mono project.

[Mono Faq:Technical](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical) (Search for compact framework)
[Forum posting: dev for Windows Mobile 5](http://www.gotmono.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.pl?num=1160214233) (Where I found the link above)