# Creating ELF image

Tags: windows, linux, shared-libraries, elf

I need to create an ELF image file from shared objects (.so files) and write it to another partition in Windows. Then open this partition in Linux and load the shared objects.

Does anybody know how to create an ELF image (a bundle of many shared objects) in Windows?

Comment: Why? This is a recipe for a ton of trouble and distress compared to just doing the work on Linux.

Comment: @bmargulies: you are right, but this is what my manager wants :(

Comment: I should apologize for asking a wrong question. What I needed was creating elf shared objects with `gcc` toolchain, creating a partition image and mounting it with `VDK` of Windows 7, then copying the shared objects to the mounted folder. Later, I can unmount and copy the partition image to Linux; mount it there and get the required files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cygwin and try a suitable GCC cross-toolchain. Perhaps you'll have to build it yourself first (which is troublesome), but there it goes...

**EDIT:**
Okay, here you are:

**A simplified one:**
[Building GCC cross compiler (from "Linux" to "Windows")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474673/building-gcc-cross-compiler-from-linux-to-windows) -- the basic steps are the same as described there. You'll just need to `./configure` it with relevant `--host=...` and `--target=...`. And oh! Don't forget to set the build root, since building "in the source tree" is not supported -- you'll just get stuck in errors if you try (I did...)

**A killer one:**
http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_install_a_newer_version_of_GCC#Build_and_Install_GCC -- a complete guide.

Comment: can you guide me about trying a "suitable GCC cross-toolchain"? and, why do I need Cygwin? Wouldn't it work with GCC on Windows?

Comment: GCC and all the helper applications from BinUtils are UNIX applications. As far as I know, there are no native Windows ports of it except for MinGW, but everything I could find about MinGW cross-compilation is "*nix-hosted to Windows", and not the other way. I'll now update the post with some (hopefully) useful links I've found while doing a similar research.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Linux understands NTFS. At least, it should be able to read off it.
You can also use a flash stick formatted as FAT32 or NTFS as the shared storage.
You can also run Linux in a VM and set up FTP server on it and exchange files through it.
There're many ways of sharing data between different OSes.

Comment: I can't use NTFS. I should use a proprietary file system similar to FAT32.
Do you know how to create an image composed of a few files in Windows? Then I will write the image to this partition.

Comment: @mustafa: Um... The `mkisofs` tool can create CD/DVD ISO images. If you can write them to the shared storage (hard drive partition?) and then mount them in Linux with `mount`, that's one way of doing it... There are probably other tools, but I don't know them.

Comment: thanks for your comment. `mkisofs` seems to be an uncontinued project "Note: I no longer maintain mkisofs.  The information on this page was current in March 1999 and has not been updated since then."